# Convert KML to GeoJSON with ogr2ogr and remove KML special attributes

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, ogr, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to convert KML to GeoJSON (or some other formats) using `ogr2ogr`  ([look at this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174622/how-to-access-shapefile-metadata-and-metatypes-information-using-ogr/174647#174647)). It's all working fine, except of one problem:

I'm always receiving these  metadata attributes with any operation (using `org2ogr` or `ogrinfo` or Python script)

> Name, description, timestamp, begin, end, altitudeMode, tessellate,
>   extrude, visibility, drawnOrder,icon

But my Schema doesn't have these fields:

```
<Schema name="distritos_mad" id="distritos_mad">
    <SimpleField name="ID" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="CD_GEOCODS" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="NM_SUBDIST" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Nomes" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="AREA (HA)" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Pop (2010)" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Ddem p/km" type="float"></SimpleField>
</Schema>
```

Looking at [LIBKML Drive documentation](http://www.gdal.org/drv_libkml.html) I realize that this fields are "special fields" and for an unknown reason this fields are included on feature properties.

How can I prevent OGR from writing these feature attributes?

I'm runing this command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" C:\out.json C:\in.kml -t_srs EPSG:4326 -dim 2 --config OGR_FORCE_ASCII NO
```

> GDAL 1.11.3, released 2015/09/16

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just use the `sql` argument in `ogr2ogr`. For instance, with the following polygon Shapefile with two features and two attributes:

```
$>ogrinfo -so -al polygon.shp
INFO: Open of `polygon.shp'
  using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

 Layer name: polygon
 Geometry: Polygon
 Feature Count: 2
 Extent: (-1.206294, -0.828671) - (0.727273, 0.566434)
 Layer SRS WKT:
 GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
       SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137,298.257223563]],
   PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
   UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]] 
id: Integer (10.0)
area: Real (6.1)
```

Assuming the above Shapefile has been converted to KML, you could do the following:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON polygon.json polygon.kml -sql 'SELECT id, area FROM polygon'
```

Which will give the following GeoJSON output:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 1, "area": 0.300000 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -0.870629370629371, 0.566433566433566 ], [ -0.534965034965035, 0.43006993006993 ], [ -0.534965034965035, 0.43006993006993 ], [ -0.517482517482518, 0.195804195804196 ], [ -0.765734265734266, -0.129370629370629 ], [ -1.206293706293706, 0.048951048951049 ], [ -0.870629370629371, 0.566433566433566 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 2, "area": 0.500000 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 0.108391608391608, -0.136363636363636 ], [ 0.199300699300699, 0.454545454545455 ], [ 0.727272727272727, -0.185314685314685 ], [ 0.433566433566433, -0.828671328671329 ], [ -0.153846153846154, -0.342657342657343 ], [ 0.108391608391608, -0.136363636363636 ] ] ] } }
]}
```

If you don't pass the `-sql` option you will get all of the additional fields from the KML file.

Comment: I'm in a situation where the name of the layer, and the field names are unknown. Special KML fields are not present, only referenced above. The ogr should return only the fields that are present in the <schema>, right? But it returns the schema fields and the special fields.
In adiction the ogrinfo also shows me this "special fields" also

Comment: I'd propose you ask this question at https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/gdal-dev and report back again here.

Comment: Can you use an EXCEPT statement in the SQL to exclude the names of the columns you know in combination with SELECT *

Comment: That's the point, I don't know any column names.